# get_avatar won't show uploaded avatar, only default gravatar

Tags: php, avatar, gravatar

I'm using the Simple Local Avatars plugin so my bbPress forumgoers can upload their own avatars. Now, when a user logs in, I want his/her avatar to display next to the relevant links (i.e. logout, edit profile, etc.). I tried the call below but it only keeps showing the default mystery man gravatar.

`<?php echo get_avatar( $current_user->user_login, 48 ); ?>`

Is there something I overlooked? How can I get the user's uploaded avatar to show up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And of course as soon as I post the question, I find the answer.

*slaps forehead*

```
<?php
        global $current_user;
        get_currentuserinfo();
        echo get_avatar( $current_user->ID, 48 );
 ?>
```